How can I fix the labels and lines on this radial chart?
I'm trying to create something for my next presentation. It's about average waiting time for a line in a store. I'm using R and ggplot. This is the data and the code that I'm using.
## Data
Store = data.frame(Line = c("Line 1","Line 2","Line 3","Line 4","Line 5","Line 6"),
                  Avg_wait_per_min = c(4.2,4.4,6.4,5.7,3.2,5.3))

Duration = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)

## Library
library(tidyverse)

## Plotting
ggplot(Store, aes(x = reorder(Line,Avg_wait_per_min),y = Avg_wait_per_min,
       fill = Line)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .95) +
geom_text(aes(label = Avg_wait_per_min), y = -0.15, hjust = 0.5, angle=90, size=3,
          color="black",position = "identity") +
geom_hline(yintercept = Duration, color = "grey", size = .75, linetype = "solid") +
geom_text(data = data.frame(y = Duration), aes(x = Inf, y = y,
          label = paste0(Duration, "'")), color = "black", size = 4, hjust = 1,
          inherit.aes = F, fontface = "bold", nudge_x = 0.1) +
labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
coord_radial(theta = "y", start = 4.42, direction = 1, clip = "off",
             inner.radius =.5) +
theme_void() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    legend.position = 'bottom',
    legend.text = element_text(size = 7),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.key.size = unit(.4,'cm')) +
scale_x_discrete() +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,7), breaks = Duration,
                   label = paste0(Duration, "'")) +
scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T)

And this is the chart that I'm getting

I have been looked everywhere, asking AIs, but none of them worked the way I wanted.
Basically I wanted to recreate chart like this:
Stranger Songs by Karamanis
But more simple. I also been looking at his code, but I don't understand how to implement his code into mine. Can someone help me with how can I make my radial chart tidier?
For example:
a) How to make the labels number from Duration appears neatly outside the circle and not piling up.
b) How to make the grey lines all the way to the center of the circle.
etc.
Thank you in advanced!!

Something like this.

geom_hline replaced by annotate with negative x, inner.radius set to 0.
Y axis labels left as is instead of geom_text. Theme changed to minimal and grids removed.
X labels have y = 0 and hjust a little above 1 to align the labels

## Data
Store = data.frame(Line = c("Line 1","Line 2","Line 3","Line 4","Line 5","Line 6"),
                   Avg_wait_per_min = c(4.2,4.4,6.4,5.7,3.2,5.3))

Duration = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)

## Library
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite

## Plotting
ggplot(Store, aes(x = reorder(Line,Avg_wait_per_min),y = Avg_wait_per_min,
                  fill = Line)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .95) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Avg_wait_per_min), y = 0, 
            hjust = 1.2, vjust = 0.5, 
            angle = 90, size = 3,
            color="black",position = "identity") +
  annotate("segment", 
           x = -5, xend = length(Duration), 
           y = Duration, yend = Duration, 
           col = "grey", linewidth = .75, linetype = "solid") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  coord_radial(theta = "y", start = 4.42, direction = 1, clip = "off",
               inner.radius =0) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.text = element_text(size = 7),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.key.size = unit(.4,'cm')) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,7), breaks = Duration,
                     label = paste0(Duration, "'")) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T)


Created on 2024-12-17 with reprex v2.0.2
